# psexec: vbs-script permission denied

Tags: windows, cmd, remote-access, psexec

With this command I want to execute my vbs-script on my second Computer, but I get the message back, that permission denied

```
Psexec.exe \\computer2 test.vbs
```

I also tried it with different Syntax, for example with an admin-account

```
Psexec.exe \\computer2 test.vbs -u user -p Alpha
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Where is `test.vbs` - local or remote computer?

Comment: @DavidPostill it is on the local Computer at the same Location as the psexec.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to execute my vbs-script on my second Computer, but I get "permission denied"

You need to execute the `.vbs` file on the remote machine using `cscript`:

```
psexec.exe \\computer2 -u user -p Alpha c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe test.vbs
```

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [Running vbscript with psexec?](https://serverfault.com/questions/202271/running-vbscript-with-psexec)
- [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) - Execute a command-line process on a remote machine. Execute a command-line process on a remote machine.